# QBCore.Functions.GetPlayerData() is empty

Tags: lua, frameworks, fivem

Hie there,

I try to spawn automatically when i login to the last location i was in the game. i use the framework qbcore

So, when we click at the button "play" on qb-multicharacter/html/index.html i change the axios call:

```
                            // axios.post('https://tr-multicharacter/selectCharacter', {
                            //     cData: data
                            // });
                            // setTimeout(function() {
                            //     viewmodel.show.characters = false
                            // }, 500)
                            

                           axios.post('https://tr-spawn/spawnplayer', {
                                spawnloc: 'current',
                                typeLoc: 'current',
                                player: data
                            });
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                viewmodel.show.characters = false
                            }, 500)
```

in qb-spawn/client.lua i've done this :

```
RegisterNUICallback('spawnplayer', function(data, cb)
    
    
    DoScreenFadeOut(10)
    
    SetTimecycleModifier('default')
    SetCamActive(cam, false)
    DestroyCam(cam, true)
    RenderScriptCams(false, false, 1, true, true)
    FreezeEntityPosition(PlayerPedId(), false)
    SetNuiFocus(false, false)
    ShutdownLoadingScreenNui()
    SetEntityAsMissionEntity(charPed, true, true)
    DeleteEntity(charPed)

    local location = tostring(data.spawnloc)
    local type = tostring(data.typeLoc)
    local ped = PlayerPedId()
    print(ped)
    pp = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayerData()
    print(pp.money)
```

but the pp print "nil"

how to get the player data ?
thx